# Creating an algebraic data type in Haskell which has either an Int or an array of them

Tags: haskell, functor, algebraic-data-types

What I require is a data type that either contains an exact value or contains a list of possible candidates. (I will be using values of type Int).

What I would want is that if I perform an `f: Int -> ...` function on a `Cell` which has an exact value it is performed on the value and if I perform a function of the form `f : [Int] -> ...` on a `Cell` with candidates it performs the function on the array of candidates. Hence I define my data like this:

```
data Cell a = Exactly a | Candidates [a] deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

instance Functor Cell where  
    fmap f (Exactly x) = Exactly (f x)  
    fmap f (Candidates (x:xs)) = Candidates ( f (x:xs))
```

This does not compile and gives me an error of the form

`Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ [b]  ...`

If I edit my code to

`fmap f (Candidates (x:xs)) = Candidates ( map f (x:xs))`

this does compile but then does not serve my function well as sometimes I would have to work on the whole array rather than the members element-wise.

Thanks for help.

Comment: *“...as sometimes I would have to work on the whole array rather than the members...”* This means that a functor instance isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @AJFarmar Uhm I am a newbie to Haskell. What would you recommend then instead of  a functior?

Comment: Writing functions specifically for the use case you want, not `fmap`.

Comment: `fmap` is meant to apply to all the items of type `a` in a container. If you need something else, do not call it `fmap`, and do not use `Functor`.

Comment: Why not just using a single (non-empty) list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this line

```
fmap f (Candidates (x:xs)) = Candidates ( f (x:xs))
```

the function `f` works only on single values and you are trying to apply it to a list.  What you need to do is apply f to each element in the list.

Try:

```
fmap f (Candidates xs) = Candidates ( fmap f xs)
```

This will apply f to each member of xs.

---

As an aside, have you read [this article](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad) (or similar) about the list monad?